# Type declaration removing "Array" around types without losing names

Tags: typescript, types, mapped-types

I'm working on a project with a friend and we wanted to create a type where the type has the first value of the key in an interface, and if they match the rest should match the parameters of the function associated.

```
export default interface ClientToServerEvents {
    'authenticate': (token: string) => void;
    'update-title': (title: string, annoteId: string) => void;
}
type Partial<T> = { [P in keyof T]: [P, Parameters<T[P]>]; };
type ClientToServerEventsType = ValueOf<Partial<ClientToServerEvents>>;
```

This is what we have got so far which results in a type that looks like:

```
type ClientToServerEventsType = ["authenticate", string] | ["update-title", string, string]
```

This is almost what we want, but we would want the type to keep the names of the parameters as well, and not just be string. What we want is:

```
type ClientToServerEventsType = ["authenticate", token: string] | ["update-title", title: string, annoteId: string]
```

We have been at it for an hour and cannot find anything.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tuple elements must all either be named or all not named. Since your tuple does not have a name for the first element, all the other names will be erased.

If you name the first element, you will see the names are preserved:

```
type AllParams<T extends Record<keyof T, (...a: any)=> any>> = { 
  [P in keyof T]: [name: P, ...rest: Parameters<T[P]>]; 
};
type ClientToServerEventsType = ValueOf<AllParams<ClientToServerEvents>>;
//  [name: "authenticate", token: string] | [name: "update-title", title: string, annoteId: string]
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAE2AMwIYFcA28CWA7GYKNAY2DgGFMdgCAVCAZSIDciBRNggZzgG8AUHGFwA5BhgALWjBwlUhUQC44AChgQA1rRXcYUfAHMAlHAC8APjgsIOBAG4hI0ejAIFwALSyYmYMrUfP119IwAaOFQ8PAhCAEkEEIM8E3MrGztHAF8BGABPMHIANVRMdGAAeWQAHjorMzg6AG1tPIhkRoBdXILyAEFMTAAFVChUAFtuWrhQQjwEXgAlYBJoBGrW9saI1QA6fdQVKLzjS0i8PIt6-jgnJqG4fDhNjrpOlSa8CeAVIYj93ZQYB6X6jb6EKBTZpDToWTr2W5ZRz5QqUagyBjMKBsKCcGTcOi9cxwEplSo1AbDMGTapUGj0JisDhcGDcK6OAD0HOEn2+KgARBJpAQ5B5+RENNo8EkjJ04AAfOC88Y-OD81zuQjeHC+YDiuBBVV6ZKGCJRGLxRJwY2yoA)

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you for the help!